# How to combine two databases in one stored procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I have a SP which should run on the DB1 (use DB1), using some tables from this DB1 and combining with DB2 tables.

I receive an error if I run this SP on DB1, but it works nice if I change the connection to the DB2. 
The problem is that I'm not allowed to create SP on this DB2.

Of course I have a DB prefix in my queries.

Comment: Try to rephrase your question. Also add more information, maybe some pseudo code (or the code itself). It is unclear what you are asking.

Comment: What DB are you using?

Comment: Sorry, I cannot insert my pseudo code. How can I do it?

Comment: @Sam just type it in. Psuedo code is just normal text. Just edit the question and type it in.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE CheckForShipment

AS
BEGIN

Create DB1.TempTable 
(a,b,c,d)

insert into DB1.TempTable

select a,b,c,d 
from DB1.ShipmentData as aa 
left join
(select e,f,g,h
from  DB2.SysTable 
) as bb on aa.a = bb.e

-------------
declare 
@b  nvarchar(max),
@c  nvarchar(max),
@Sc  nvarchar(max),
@Me  nvarchar(max);

Declare ListOfShipments
For
Select b,c,d from DB1.TempTable 
Open ListOfShipments

FETCH NEXT FROM ListOfShipments INTO @b,@b,@d

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  
BEGIN

    exec (@Sc)

    SET  @Me = something 

    FETCH NEXT FROM ListOfShipments

    END
    CLOSE ListOfShipments
    DEALLOCATE ListOfShipments
-----------------

---SEND EMAIL 

EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail
    @profile_name = etc.
enter code here

Drop table DB1.TempTable 

End
```